# Root node in a tree should be expanded by default

Tags: tree, root-node

I need only Root node to be expanded by default. Can anybody help me with this. Following is the HTML and Jquery.

It has a expand and collapse functionality. When u click on text in a tree it will expand and collapse.

I have added in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FFc7z/

```
    <div>
         <ul id ="expList">
                <li>
                    Root
                    <ul>
                        <li>

                            Child 1
                            <ul>
                                <li>                             
                                    Subchild 1</li>
                                <li>                                
                                    Subchild 2</li>
                                <li>                              
                                   Subchild 3</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>

                            Child 2
                            <ul>
                                <li>                                
                                    Subchild 1</li>
                                <li>Subchild 2</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                <li>
                   child3
                </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

Jquery

 $(document).ready( function() {
      prepareList()
  });

function prepareList() {
  $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)')
    .click( function(event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        return false;
    })
    .addClass('collapsed')
    .children('ul').hide();
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
$('#expList>li>ul').show();
```

as a last line of prepareList() function